# WQ Query post meta date comparison

Tags: wp-query

I need to perform a query on some post meta which currently stores the date time lie so `31/07/2012` I need to check to see if this post meta is greater than the current date and if true return it in the query.

I can't work out a way to do this with WP_Query using the provided methods.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your post to add some code.  If I had to guess, I'd wager you need to convert your dates to timestamps for numerical comparison, otherwise you're comparing strings.

Comment: I suggest save the date in timestamp it will be easier and fast to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bit of a problem. The only human calendar format that sorts correctly is `YYYY/MM/DD`, the separators are optional. You have `DD/MM/YYYY`. Whoever decided to store in that format made a bad decision.

Your best option is to correct that design decision and convert those dates to `YYYY-MM-DD` or to a Unix Timestamp. You can also use MySQL's date format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` but you don't have hours minutes and seconds. That should be fairly simple. You'd query the database, use PHP to change the format, and save the new dates back to the database. If you do that you can use normal WordPress tools, such as `WP_Query`, to retrieve the information. Of course, you'd also have to alter whatever code created the problem in the first place.

Otherwise you will have to do something like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
  RIGHT(columnname,4),
  SUBSTR(columnname,4,2),
  LEFT(columnname,2)
) AS date
FROM `tablename`
WHERE id = 1
ORDER BY date
```

And you ***will not*** be able to use WordPress Core tools for the queries. `WP_Query`-- `MySQL` really-- can sort alphabetically(ish) or numerically but not "calendarmerically". To sort according to a calendar date you have to get the date into a format that sorts numerically or one that MySQL's built in date functions can deal with. I should also note that that query is not likely to be very efficient.